# How to handle rate limits with Bigcommerce PHP SDK

Tags: php, bigcommerce, rate-limiting

I've built an application that uses the Bigcommerce PHP SDK to access their API. In various parts of my application I use methods from the SDK to perform various tasks. For example, if I need to get a product from the client's store, I will write the following in my script:

```
Bigcommerce::getProduct(123);
```

Other times, I may need to get an order, or a handful or orders or products, or edit a product. Reading the documentations for the Bigcommerce API explains that they will rate limit calls, and if the rate limit is hit, they respond with an error code to alert you that you must wait a certain number of seconds before making your next API call.  You can read about that here (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/rate-limits/basic).

One way to adhere to these rate limits would be to add something like the following code after every single place in my application that I call the Bigcommerce API:

```
$product = Bigcommerce::getProduct(123);

if(!$product){
    if(Bigcommerce::getLastError()->code == 429){
        sleep(Bigcommerce::connection()->getHeader("X-Retry-After"));

        //get the product again
        $product = Bigcommerce::getProduct(123);
    }
}
```

However, this can quickly become an enormous pain the manage every time I call the API.  My question is, should I be writing my own function to handle the calling the API, that has the rate limit check built in to it. Something like:

```
function callBigcommerceApi($method, $args)
{

    $response = Bigcommerce::$method($args);

    if(!$response){

        if(Bigcommerce::getLastError()->code == 429){

            sleep(Bigcommerce::connection()->getHeader("X-Retry-After"));

            callBigcommerceApi($method, $args);
        }
        else{

            return $response;
        }
    }

}
```

Or, should I somehow be integrating a function like this into the SDK itself, so that anytime any method from the SDK is called, it will be subject to the rate limit and know how to handle it?